# Rewriting loop without breaks

Tags: python, loops, break

Below is the code that I want to replicate without using break
///

```
while True:
    choice = input("Is it time to choose(Y/N)? ")
    if choice.upper() == "N": 
        break
    idx = random.randint(0, len(contents))
    fnd = False
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if table[i][j] == contents[idx]:
                table[i][j] = "SEEN"
                fnd = True
                break
        if fnd:
            break
    won = check_win(table)
    print_table(table)
    if won:
        print("The game has been won!!")
        break
```

Can't figure out, already tried using variables but can't make it work

Comment: This is confused by you having `break` statements in nested loops (ironically, that's part of why I don't use `break` statements if I can help it.) Is it intentional that after setting `fnd` to true you continue the rest of the code, or was that third `break` supposed to exit the top level while loop?

Comment: In general, a description of what you're trying to do might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag instead:

```py
w_flag = True
while w_flag:
    choice = input("Is it time to choose(Y/N)? ")
    if choice.upper() == "N": 
        w_flag = False
    
    if w_flag:
        idx = random.randint(0, len(contents))
        fnd = False
        i,j = 0,0
        i_flag = True
        while i < 3 and i_flag:
            j_flag = True
            while j < 3 and j_flag:
                if table[i][j] == contents[idx]:
                    table[i][j] = "SEEN"
                    fnd = True
                    j_flag = False
                j += 1
            if fnd:
                i_flag = False
            i += 1
        
        won = check_win(table)
        print_table(table)
        if won:
            print("The game has been won!!")
            w_flag = False
```

Comment: This does not do what the original code does - `break` breaks out of the closest loop level, not the top level. What happens in the `for` statements is different from the `while` statements. Additionally, this does not short-circuit out of the inner loops - your code may set multiple cells to `SEEN`, which the original would not.

Comment: ok - I think I have covered by bases now :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's handle this case by case. (I'm leaving initializing variables up to you, btw.)

```
while True:
    choice = input("Is it time to choose(Y/N)? ")
    if choice.upper() == "N": 
        break
```

The above break statement could be removed by having a `playing` variable. Change `while True:` to `while playing`, and then set `playing` to false if the player chooses; put the rest of the loop body in the `else` branch.

```
    idx = random.randint(0, len(contents))
    fnd = False
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if table[i][j] == contents[idx]:
                table[i][j] = "SEEN"
                fnd = True
                break
        if fnd:
            break
```

I'm taking the above two `break` statements to be independent of the top-level `while` loop, as that's the way it's currently coded. You could re-code these as two nested `while` loops that increment counters- `while i < 3 && !fnd` and `while j < 3 && !fnd`, though that's messy. The inner one could also be handled with `index()`

```
    won = check_win(table)
    print_table(table)
    if won:
        print("The game has been won!!")
        break
```

This last one is the easiest: Just change the loop condition to `while playing && !won`

That's messy, but it should be equivalent. I might be able to make it cleaner if I knew what you were trying to do with the code as a whole.